# Arcanist/Phabricator How to override a linter's bin locally

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

Our linter is configured in a .arcconfig file in a project.

I would like to locally override it to be `/usr/local/bin/php56 phpcs` instead of the default `phpcs`.

However I do not want to alter the config file as that is in the repository, how can I override this only for my local machine?